# Kerberos Spnego in Spring and Angular frontend + JWT

Tags: angular, spring, kerberos, spnego

My main goal is to have a Kerberos authentication first and if it fails have an Angular's form page that send a post with username/password to `/users/login`.

I have configured pretty much [as follow](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-kerberos) in Spring and already made a login/password authentication that sends back a JWT, with guards in the frontend. The frontend is served in the resources folder of Spring.

Kerberos does not seem to pop up/auto log. Is there something specific to do ?

Is creating a filter after the Kerberos login the right way to process the authentication in the frontend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because my Spnego configuration was using a `SpnegoEntryPoint("/#/login")` and/or the Spring Security was using `.formLogin().loginPage("/#/login").permitAll()` and since Spnego uses **Forward** and not **Redirect**, he couldn't find the page server side and threw a 404 instead of a 401.

401 is what triggers a Kerberos Authentication coupled with the header `WWW-Authorization: Negotiate`. So since it threw a 404, it never did initiate the Kerberos Authentication.

Therefore, I changed both `/#/login` to `/index.html` (`/` would probably work).

Then, Angular side (in `app.component.ts`), I trigger an API call on a secure endpoint `/connect` and my `CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java` registered to my filter simply decorate the header with a JWT Token in the header `Authorization : Bearer`

```
UserDetails authUser = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
httpServletResponse.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING,
                SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + TokenUtil.generateToken(authUser));
```

I then simply take the header, store it in LocalStorage, redirect the user to the page.